# Warnings using Netbeans 8.2 and Bootstrap 4

Tags: netbeans, warnings, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 a lot of warnings show up  in Netbeans vs. 8.2  saying that  certain classes are not found – all the classes belong to Bootstrap 4. This is rather irritating. These warnings however don't seem to influence the project.
The css file is imported using CDN.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

What is the reason for these warnings and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: You can ignore this error, I think it will work fine. Actually Netbeans 8.2 is not perfectly compatible with bootstrap 4. Or try to update all the plugins of Netbeans 8.2

Answer (score -1):

Hi just ignore that message ,  the tag is OK but netbeans show you a error cause the tag is too big and contains the property integrity. Everything is ok in your app. Try with another IDE and the error is not aviable.

Comment: Hi Alfredo, it is very regrettable that this problem is not solved as it exists for many month now. You never know if one of these warnings is a serious one. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hi not problem , actually  netbeans shows you errors in .min files but is working well the files . No worries. Just netbeans doesn't know the sintax.